# Assign marks to questions and then add them all up

Tags: lists, counters, exam

I would like to assign and tally up points on LaTeX.

Here is a snip it of my exam paper.

```
\documentclass{exam}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\arabic*}\hspace{4mm}]

\item Given $z=\displaystyle2(\cos(\frac{\pi}{3})+i\sin(\frac{\pi}{3}))$, which expression is equal to $(\bar{z})^{-1}$?

\item Simplify $i^{2019}$.\begin{enumerate}[label=(\Alph*),leftmargin=0.85cm,itemsep=2ex] \item $1$\item $i$\item $-i$\item $-1$ \end{enumerate}\vskip 9mm

\end{enumerate}
```

How do I create a counter and add some command in front or the end of my questions (`\item`) so that I can tally up the total marks at the end.

To be honest, I looked around the web but I couldn't find any commands that allows me to create my own counter and then display the final results.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Please have a look at package `xsim`. It should do what you want, and provides even some more nice features.

Comment: @Johannes_B I am having a look at it right now. Thanks

Comment: This class allows you to add the points, you can use `\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}` and then retrieve the points for a question and so on.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat that requires me to use commands like \question to all my questions. at the moment, all my questions are setup based on \item.

Comment: I see. But why do you then use the `exam` class, i.e. which of its features are you using?

Comment: I know but the setup of the questions are done using the enumerate package. I just wanted it to be flexible across all document classes i.e exam/article etc.

Comment: It's not clear why you insist on using `itemize` when you can just use the features of the `exam` class, so write `\question[10]` or `\part[5]` and the output will have numbered  questions and parts with the number of points to be earned properly displayed, like `4 question (10 points)` and the number of points automatically added up if needed.  One can also have solutions to problems which are optionally displayed for a solution sheet.  I have used `exam` for at least 10 years.  Very high quality package with a great, easily understood documentation.  It even has multiple choice test feature